# SQLite Temp Table in Navicat

Tags: sqlite

I use Navicat and this command to create temp table in sqlite:

```
create temp table search as select * from documents
```

Then when i try to query:

```
select * from search
```

I got:

```
no such table: temp.sqlite_master
```

or:

```
no such table
```

The table doesn't appear in table list too, but when I try to create it again I get:

```
table search already exists
```

What is the problem? is it from navicat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like a bug in SQLite DLL shipped with Navicat. Test it somewhere else worked ok.

Answer (score 2):

You create statement looks correct to me.  When you create a temp table it is deleted when you close the connection string used to create the table.  Are you closing the connection after you create the table and then opening it again when you are sending the query?

If not, can you include your query statement too?

Comment: no, exactly after I create it, even in the same query window. if I close and open again it can be created again.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of SQLite tells this about CREATE TABLE:

> If a  is specified, it must be either "main", "temp",
>   or the name of an attached database. In this case the new table is
>   created in the named database. If the "TEMP" or "TEMPORARY" keyword
>   occurs between the "CREATE" and "TABLE" then the new table is created
>   in the temp database. It is an error to specify both a 
>   and the TEMP or TEMPORARY keyword, unless the  is
>   "temp". If no database name is specified and the TEMP keyword is not
>   present then the table is created in the main database.

May be you should accesse table via temp prefix like this: `temp.search`.